# Renders turning black before certain frame

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm new to Blender and already tried everything Google threw at me, so I don't know what else to do.

I'm using Eevee, there are lights in my scene, but the renders appear fine for a little moment and then turn black and save as black.
[image: Blender render, pitch black]

But after a certain frame (1727, in particular), the renders go back to normal.

[image: Blender Render, frame 1727, normal]

I'm not using the compositor, but need the sequencer for audio.

[image: Post Processing/Compositing Off, Sequencer On]

And nothing is blocking the camera before frame 1727.

Another detail is that, before frame 1727, the viewport shading looks completely black too.

[image: Viewport Shading pitch black before frame 1727]

Comment: are you sure there's not an object moving in front of your camera?

Comment: Completely sure. The viewport shading even looks black outside the camera view

Comment: could you please only keep one object and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Also double check that you didn't hide objects in the viewport, but not in the render. Are there keyframe on the lights (location or power)?